# Isfirstresponder swift issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I get a "Method does not override any method from its superclass" for a is first responder function. I looked this up online and theres no solution. could you please help me fix this. Here is the code.

```
public override func isFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    // Return true if any of `self`'s subviews is the current first responder.
    // Needs to unwrap the IBOutlets otherwise IBInspectable is crashing when using CardTextField because IBOutlets
    // are not initialized yet when IBInspectable engine runs.
    guard let numberInputTextField = numberInputTextField, let monthTextField = monthTextField, let yearTextField = yearTextField, let cvcTextField = cvcTextField else {
        return false
    }

    return [numberInputTextField, monthTextField, yearTextField, cvcTextField]
        .filter({$0.isFirstResponder})
        .isEmpty == false
}
```

Here is an image of the error

[Error of IsFirstResponderError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLBDO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
public override func isFirstResponder() -> Bool {
```

with this:

```
public override var isFirstResponder: Bool {
```

[Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621145-isfirstresponder)